# Working with Spring FeignClient with fallback behavior

Tags: spring, microservices, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I got a problem to solve with Spring FeignClient.

I have two endpoints to send an SMS, both are the same behavior:

- When I send a GET with all query parameters required, the service sends the SMS.
- But I need to check if endpoint A is off – in which case I must send to endpoint B, both with the same request path and payload.

How can I solve this problem?

Today I have an interface with FeignClient annotation and just one URL.
I tried to make use a FeignBuilder to create the request in runtime and change the URL but without success.

How can I use Feign to control service fallback in client side, like:

```
@Value(${sms.urls})
List<String> endPoints;

for (endPoint : endPoints){
  if(endPoint.isUp())
  return makeRequest(endPoint).
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With regards to using FeignBuilder, maybe you can find an answer to your problem [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR6/#_creating_feign_clients_manually)

If this doesn't work, I would suggest creating a wrapper class around the interface. 
When I had to deal with such a problem in the past I simply created a class that uses the Feign client interface. Spring will handle the wiring for you based on the fact that you annotated your feign client with the @FeignClient annotation. This way you can modify the behavior from the wrapper class. You'd write your fallback logic in a method and call the feign client as needed.

Hope this helps

Comment: I found link that make easy to implement a fallback function:
https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/pull/308/files

But now when i try to call Feign with builder:
HystrixFeign.builder()
                    .contract(new SpringMvcContract())
                    .target(AtlasFeignClient.class, this.url);
Feign cannot parse the application.propertie value configured in spring config, they send a request for unparsed url like method: get url: /${some.propertie}

Comment: Thanks for the link! I wonder if you tried to use Spring (without Feign, using @Value("config_name")) to retrieve the config and then inject them in the Feign builder manually, maybe it could work? Just a suggestion.